# Permitir maximizar e minimizar janelas no PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um programa de texto/notas, como o Word ou o bloco de notas no PySimpleGUI. Antes de começar a faze-lo, precisei de programas de teste, e em um deles eu tenho um problema: permitir maximizar e retornar ao tamanho original.
Pesquisei bastante e encontrei o `maximize`, em que maximizava a tela, mas não permitia alternar. Até que eu pensei que poderia ter um `event` para isso, e eu simplesmente não encontro nada a respeito.
Segue meu código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('Default1')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('oi')]
    ]
x = sg.Window('teste', layout=layout, finalize=True, size = (600,600))
x.maximize()
while True:
    event, values = x.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

Então como eu poderia ativar a maximização/retornar ao tamanho original da janela no PySimpleGUI?

Estou utilizando o Windows 10 Pro, 64bit.

Por favor, qualquer erro na pergunta comentem para eu alterá-la!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olhando a **[documentação](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#window) <sup>(readthedocs.io)</sup>**, veja que tem a opção `resizable = False,`, o padrão é `False` então basta ajustar para `True`, exemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [  [sg.Text('Foo')],
            [sg.Text('Bar'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Confirmar'), sg.Button('Cancelar')] ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, resizable = True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancelar':
        break

    print('Você escreveu: ', values[0])

window.close()
```